# Ionic 2 nested routes and/or customizing side-menus by component?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript, ionic-framework

i'm testing Ionic 2 and i want a nav flow like this:

Page 1: Login

Page 2: List of notebooks (notes is just an example) and a `side menu` to change between categories, kind like folders.

Page 3: Here's the tricky part, i want that when getting inside the notebook, the side menu changes to reflect the notes available while showing a note in the center of content.

As the ionic 2 tutorial is made the `routes` in the `sidenav` are set with a `*ng-for` loop, to change the sidemenu i would have to make a global variable or link it with a service or databinding.

Can't link as expected because the `ion-nav` directive doesn't link to the controller of the component routed to.

Is there a way to nest routes? link a variable between app component and a child one through ion-nav or use a service?

If the above are not possible, it seems i will have to avoid sidemenu in the `index.html` and put it in each component template, which will lead to a lot of repetition of code.

Please comment what you don't understand and what needs clarification as this is the best explanation i can think of.